# How to programmatically enable GPS in Android Cupcake

Tags: java, android, gps, android-1.5-cupcake

I'm currently writing an app in Android that works with the GPS. At the moment I'm able to work out whether the GPS is enabled. My problem is that I want to enable the GPS on app startup if it is disabled. How can I do this programmaticaly?

Comment: depends on the version of Cupcake. 1.5 doesnt allow it apparently.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can't, starting with Android 1.5. The most you can do is pop open the activity to allow the user to toggle it on/off. Use the action held in `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS` to craft an Intent to open this activity.

Comment: Why is this disabled? Why not allow developers to toggle this? the Power Control widget can, so we should be able to as well. Dont you think?

Comment: It is disabled for privacy reasons. If the user wants GPS off, the user should have GPS off, period.

Comment: These guys seem to have figured it out.  Unfortunately the apk is obfuscated and I could not figure out how it was accomplished.  URL:https://market.android.com/details?id=at.abraxas.powerwidget.free&hl=en

Comment: @commonsware but it can actually be done by exploiting a certain loophole up to 2.2. I'm sure you know the details, but for others, see [Enable GPS programatically like Tasker](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5305835/383414)

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier: Such security loopholes have been fixed, at least for newer versions of Android.

Comment: @commonsware That is correct - fixed from 2.3 onwards (as at time of writing 20/06/2012). However some developers require a quick-n-dirty way of doing something, so I like to ensure they can find the hacks when needed.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier: I like to ensure that users can maintain their privacy and security, by maintaining complete control over whether GPS is enabled.

Answer (score 15):

```
if(!LocationManager.isProviderEnabled(android.location.LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ))
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS );
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Comment: This code didn't compile for me on android 2.2, as .isProviderEnabled is not a static method on LocationManager. Working code for me was as follows (apologies for formatting)


    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ))
    {
      Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS );
      startActivity(myIntent);
    }

Answer (score 6):

This method code can be help for you

```
private void turnGPSOnOff(){
  String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
  if(!provider.contains("gps")){
    final Intent poke = new Intent();
    poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
    poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
    poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
    sendBroadcast(poke);
    //Toast.makeText(this, "Your GPS is Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

Comment: yes **this can be done up to 2.2 (sdk 8)**. For more info, see [Enable GPS programatically like Tasker](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5305835/383414)

Answer (score 3):

You might use the following:

```
try {
  Settings.Secure.setLocationProviderEnabled(getContentResolver(), LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true);
} catch (Exception e) {
  logger.log(Log.ERROR, e, e.getMessage());
}
```

but it will only work if you have system signature protection level. So you need to cook your own Image to actually use it :/

Answer (score 1):

First check whether the location service is already on or not ??

**Checking location service is enabled or not**

```
public boolean isLocationServiceEnabled(){
    LocationManager locationManager = null;
    boolean gps_enabled= false,network_enabled = false;

    if(locationManager ==null)
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try{
        gps_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        //do nothing...
    }

    try{
        network_enabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        //do nothing...
    }

    return gps_enabled || network_enabled;

}
```

**Then finally to open if location service in turned off previously**

```
  if (isLocationServiceEnabled())) {
          //DO what you need...
     } else {
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
          builder.setMessage("Seems Like location service is off,   Enable this to show map")
      .setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                             Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }).setNegativeButton("NO THANKS", null).create().show();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Location Settings Dialog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/03/google-play-services-70-places-everyone.html) in Play Services that prompts the user to enable location services (if necessary) with just one click.

Answer (score -5):

if your question is at the user level of android these properties are located in: `"Settings -> Location -> Use wireless networks" -> "Settings -> Location -> Use GPS satellites"`.

But at the developer can use the class `"android.provider.Settings.Secure"` with the appropriate permissions.

Comment: This is not the answer, the person who ask the question wanted