# How can we turn on/off GPS programatically without going on setting screen in android?

Tags: android

How can we turn on/off GPS programatically without going on setting screen in android?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this.

This is important for privacy reasons.

[How to programmatically enable GPS in Android Cupcake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051649/how-to-programmatically-enable-gps-in-android-cupcake)

Answer (score 1):

// Remove the listener you previously added

locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);

got from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Comment: +1 That's the way to go, plus it's suggested by the official android documentation.