# How to enable GPS in our App programmatically Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically enable GPS in Android Cupcake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051649/how-to-programmatically-enable-gps-in-android-cupcake)

How do I get start GPS in my smartphone programmatically, where some application requesting to start my GPS?

Comment: May be duplicate of this...see this [GPS settings programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843675/how-do-i-find-out-if-the-gps-of-an-android-device-is-enabled) Hope this helps..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically enable GPS in Android Cupcake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051649/how-to-programmatically-enable-gps-in-android-cupcake) and **many others.** Please search before you ask a question!