# Android turn off GPS

Tags: android

Can I turn ON/OFF GPS in an application? As it drains so much of battery, can I turn it OFF for some time? OR there is better solution for this .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
   locationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener); locationManager = null;
```

Answer (score 3):

You ask the user to do this, (using a toast maybe), start this activity

```
if(!LocationManager.isProviderEnabled(android.location.LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ))
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS );
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Comment: This should launch the settings screen where the user can disable GPS.

Comment: There is no way to turn on/off gps through codes....
Bringing GPS activity is the best way

Answer (score 1):

```
private void turnGPSOn(){
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}

private void turnGPSOff(){
    String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

    if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
        final Intent poke = new Intent();
        poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
        poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
        poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
        sendBroadcast(poke);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't turn it on/off yourself. You can however prompt the user to turn it off/on: [How to programmatically enable GPS in Android Cupcake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051649/how-to-programmatically-enable-gps-in-android-cupcake)

Answer (score 0):

I think as a security measure the android system won't allow you to turn on and off the gps for the user(as of android 2.0 I think). You can either stop getting updates and that supposed to stop using the gps (unless other application use it), or ask the user to switch it off.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop listening for GPS events in your application (if your application uses GPS).
for instance, using [`LocationManager.removeUpdates`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates%28android.location.LocationListener%29).

If you want to "turn off" the GPS at OS level, I think it is not possible programmatically.