# Can we Enable Use Google Location Services on 4.0 programatically?

Tags: android

I wants to Enable Use Google Location Services on my 4.0 Device From within my Application.
Can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. Go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051649/how-to-programmatically-enable-gps-in-android-cupcake). It will give you detailed information.

Comment: But this will only create a shortcut to open settings ,I want to Enable the CheckBox of Use Services from my application.

Comment: there is an app in the market that does it?how is it possible?

Comment: It likely uses an exploit from an older version of android, and that app probably wouldn't work on new versions of android. There isn't an official documented way of turning GPS on/off programmatically, much like NFC. GPS and NFC have privacy/security implications so thats why you can only manipulate them to an extent.

Comment: i don't wanna turn gps on,but i wants to enable google services programatically