# Is any possibility to switch ON the GPS provider in android programmatically?

Tags: android

Due to the battery drainage, i want to switch ON/OFF the providers programmatically that is background mode. Previously i did with settings activity of providers. But i feel it is not user friendly.

Please help me?

Comment: There is no API in Android to do this.

Comment: probably the Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051649/how-to-programmatically-enable-gps-in-android-cupcake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't control it at the system level. Only users are allowed to do that. But you can stop listening for GPS events using something like:

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener); 
locationManager = null;
```

You can also launch the settings screen so the user can do it himself using:

```
if(!LocationManager.isProviderEnabled(android.location.LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ))
{
    Intent myIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS );
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.I want to select/deselect(ON/OFF) in background mode not with UI?

Comment: as I said, that cannot and should not be done programmatically. It's up to the user to do that.

Comment: thanks!! If not means,how to overcome the battery drainage with providers? i removed the updates from providers once i got the values.

Comment: yeah. Thats good. You can also post this as another question and see what answers you get