# why I can not get location when I turned on gps with code?

Tags: android, gps, location

when I turned on gps with code,gps icon blinking in notification bar.but when I go to location setting, I see use gps sattelite option dont checked and I can not show location on phone maps.
when I go to location setting and checked use gps sattelite option, I can see my location on maps, but gps icon blinking yet on notification bar.
I think gps is not enabled actually, is right?

Answer (score 0):

Correct. GPS is most likely not enabled. Starting a long time ago, you cannot directly toggle GPS on/off.

You *can* send an intent that brings users to the settings screen, where they can change it themselves. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1051649/752320) for more details on that.